# ART Tube MP doesn't register any input.

Tags: microphone, preamp

I have a NADY SP-4C mic plugged into an ART Tube MP Studio preamp which, in turn, is plugged into my laptop's mic/line-in. All connected via 1/4" (laptop is 1/4" to 1/8", of course).

The Tube MP does not register any movement on the level meter when I talk into the mic, no matter what position the dials/buttons are in.

The only time I get needle movement is when I press/un-press the +48v/Phantom power button.

If I plug the mic directly into the laptop, I can record okay but the levels are low (which is why I bought the Tube MP).

I don't know what I'm doing audio-wise but am very technical otherwise. Am I missing something? Can someone guide me regarding what settings I should try on the Tube MP? I'm not getting any throughput at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- It's a dynamic mic, so you don't need the phantom power switch on your preamp, but it might be worth trying the 20dB boost button.
- Are you sure the on/off switch on the microphone is on? (a common mistake)
- Do you have anything else you can try plugging into your preamp (e.g. a guitar).
- Was the preamp bought new? It contains a tube, which can break.

Comment: Yes, the mic is on. I don't have another one so all I can test the input with is my Zune. Which I did and it looked like there was some action on the meter for a bit and then it just stayed pinned at the 0/red line (even after removing the input). Also while recording in that state all I hear is electronic humming.